# Add an event to client calendar through an email

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, calendar

I have absolutely no idea about how it can be done. 
All i have is a mail sending function

```
sendEmail(List<String> to, String subject, String text)
```

> How can i create an event notification email and forward it to the client, so that client
>   can add the event to his calendar by clicking an Yes Button

Answer (score 0):

No Javascript is allowed in most of the email clients. So a *Button* is not helpful to your purpose.

I think the best way is to generate a .ics file and attach it to your email. Most of the email  client (like Gmail) can find it and display as a part of email body. Usually, it will has an "add to calendar" link which is generated by email client for this .ics file.

Here is a reference to .ics file format. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar